# Regex - count number of characters to validate match

Tags: regex

My goal is to validate instagram profile links via a regular expression.
So for example this one is valid:
https://www.instagram.com/test.profile/

This one is not:
https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/test/

Using this regex

```
(?:(?:http|https):\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:instagram\.com|instagr\.am)\/([A-Za-z0-9-_\.]+)
```

On this text: `https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/test/`
produces a match `https://www.instagram.com/explore`, but this one I want to avoid and discharge.
[LIVE DEMO HERE](https://www.instagram.com/explore)

My question: is possible to add an additional syntax in the regex to validate a match ONLY if the string contains exactly 4 slashes (/)?

Comment: `^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:instagram\.com|instagr\.am)\/([\w.-]+)\/?$`? Or, is the `/` at the end obligatory? Then try `^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:instagram\.com|instagr\.am)\/([\w.-]+)\/$`, see https://regex101.com/r/frgU0j/1

Comment: / obligatoy at the end! thx Wiktor! pls send the answer so I can give kudos to y answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the `/` char obligatory if you add `\/` at the end:

```js
^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:instagram\.com|instagr\.am)\/([\w.-]+)\/$
```

Note that `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` can most probably be replaced with `\w` (especially, if it is JavaScript, PHP, Java or Ruby) to make the pattern shorter. It won't hurt even in those regex flavors where `\w` is Unicode-aware by default (Python `re`, .NET).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/frgU0j/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:https?:\/\/)?` - an optional `http://` or `https://`
- `(?:www\.)?` - an optional `www.` string
- `(?:instagram\.com|instagr\.am)` - `instagram.com` or `instagr.am`
- `\/` - a `/` char
- `([\w.-]+)`- Group 1: one or more letters, digits, `_`, `.` or `-` chars
- `\/` - a `/` char
- `$` - end of string.